# How to delete table body

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I would like to clear table body those data are previously loaded already by JavaScript.

[image]

`

```
getTableData = function (clicked_id) {
    if (clicked_id != '') {
        $.ajax({
            async   : false,
            method  : "POST",
            url     : projectRootPath+"sites/onSlectQuery/" + clicked_id
        }).done(function(msg) {
            recivedData = msg;

        }).error(function(){
            alert("Not Updated");
        });
        parseData(recivedData);
    }

    else  {

        var row = document.getElementById("myTable");
        row.clear(); 
    }
};
```

`

Actually on every AJAX execution I would like to change my view. To do so I need to clear previous data. So for that I need to delete previous data. Like below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find` on table using table ID and empty that portion.

```
$('#myTable').find('tbody').html('');
```

Another option is remove. Be careful `remove()` method takes elements out of the DOM.

```
$('#myTable').find('tbody').remove();
```

Comment: $('#myTable').find('tbody').html(''); I tried with this method earlier. Problem with this method is it clears the data for single time.... next time it doesn't clears the data.

Comment: Before bind your data call this one to clear the tbody . And it's work.

Answer (score 2):

Check below code:

```
document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].innerHTML = '';
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that i found to solve the problem is this

`$("#myTable").slice(1).remove();`